# Загрузка случайных изображений в C#

Tags: c#

Вопрос от нуба. Есть 10 изображений и 5 элементов PictureBox. Кликом по кнопке загружаются 5 случайных изображений в эти окна, как сделать, чтобы они не повторялись?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пусть есть список из 10-ти изображений. Выбираем одно случайное из него, отображаем в первом окошке и удаляем его из списка. Выбираем второе случайное изображение из оставшегося списка (уже без первого), отображаем его во втором окошке и опять удаляем из списка и повторяем далее.

Минус: происходит удаление изображений из списка, по этому для повторения процесса придется хранить оригинальный список и копировать его в рабочий из которого уже удалять. Скорость будет падать на копировании списков, но не сильно заметно, поскольку копироваться будут ссылки на изображения.

Плюс: простота реализации и надежность алгоритма (точно не повторяться изображения).

Comment: Гораздо лучше так: заводим список из 10ти чисел. Проделываем указанную операцию на этом списке, а потом просто выводим элементы списка изображений с выбранными номерами.

Comment: поначалу тоже думал про числа, но мы ничего не выйграем от этого, поскольку все равно будет 2 списка(с изображениями и числами), а объем памяти будет одинаковым (почти, хендлер на объект равен int в шарпе?)
Но при этом проиграем в наглядности.

Comment: Да в наглядности сильно не проиграем — решение через числа, по-прежнему, сильно очевидное, да и более универсальное (например, если мы выбираем не из списка с именами файлов, а с самими уже загруженными файлами — удалять\загружать файлы, если несколько раз надо будет выводить по пять картинок). Да и думается, что создание\удаление интов работает значительно быстрее, чем объектов любого вида.

Comment: @kirelagin создавать объекты не нужно, только копировать ссылки

Comment: Главное при удалении из списка чтобы ссылка где-то осталась ;).

Comment: @kirelagin так копия обязательно будет, поскольку есть оригинальный список с изображениями

Comment: @IAZ хм… не-а, в ответе нет ничего про копирование исходного списка :).

Comment: @kirelagin как это нет? см. абзац "минус". наверно если внимательнее читать, то и вопросов будет меньше? ;)

Comment: @IAZ ну блин! Я «минус» и «плюс» расцениваю просто как справку, а не ответ на вопрос… Ладно, проехали)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант хранить изображения (либо пути к ним) в списке и хранить их количество.
Вызывается рандом с текущим количеством, заносится в первый бокс, убирается из списка, уменьшается количество и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

А в чём сложность? При каждом получении имени случайного изображения, проверять было ли оно уже вставлено. Если да, то получить другое случайное изображение. Делать это до тех пор пока не получим то, которого ещё не было.